# how to deploy one instance of angular to multiple clients

Tags: angular, typescript, nginx, deployment, web-applications

I am developing an angular application which is a product and deployed to multiple clients. each client has his own database in the backend so each client has his own api. for example if client one types http://url1.com I should use his api1 and his logo1 and if client two types http://url2.com I should use his api2 and his logo2 and so on. I am looking for a config file or something that's makes me add url, api, and logo for each client want my application.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a package manager to do this. For example *yarn* or *npm* would be a good pick. By default *npm* is probably already installed on your local machine. Inside the *angular.json* file you can add different configurations for each production system.
[You can read the details in this article](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/configure-and-build-angular-application-for-different-environments-7e94a3c0af23)

---

In short: you need to duplicate *environment.prod.ts* file, name them properly, change the *angular.json* file by adding the new environments and when building the site for each URL, you need to use the `--configuration url1` command line parameter.

In detail here is a small reduced snapshot from the *angular.json* (I removed some items to make this shorter):

```
{
  "$schema":"./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version":1,
  "cli":{
    "packageManager":"npm"
  },
  "newProjectRoot":"projects",
  "projects":{
    "safe-trace-tx-ui":{
      "root":"",
      "sourceRoot":"src",
      "projectType":"application",
      "architect":{
        "build":{
          "configurations":{
            "production":{
              "budgets":[
                {
                  "type":"anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning":"20kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization":true,
              "outputHashing":"all",
              "sourceMap":false,
              "extractCss":true,
              "namedChunks":false,
              "aot":true,
              "extractLicenses":true,
              "vendorChunk":false,
              "buildOptimizer":true,
              "fileReplacements":[
                {
                  "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "local":{
              "sourceMap":true,
              "budgets":[
                {
                  "type":"initial",
                  "maximumWarning":"2mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "locales5":{
              "sourceMap":true,
              "budgets":[
                {
                  "type":"initial",
                  "maximumWarning":"2mb"
                }
              ],
              "tsConfig":"src/tsconfig.app.es5.json"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject":"safe-trace-tx-ui",
  "schematics":{
    "@schematics/angular:component":{
      "prefix":"app",
      "style":"scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive":{
      "prefix":"app"
    }
  }
}
```

Example for the *environment.ts* (you need to rename this to *environment.url1.ts*):

```
export const environment = {
    endpoints: {/* endpoint will go here */},
    production: false,
    apiBaseUrl: 'http://url1.com',
}
```

FYI: It would be a good idea to create well defined commands in the *package.json* file, so later it will be easier to run command for each environment. For example: npm run build-url1. This command should look like this inside you *package.json* file:

```
"build:url1": "ng build --prod --configuration:url1"
```

---

For the logo1, logo2 please also use the *environment.ts* file. You can create you logos inside your project src folder. Reference each logos in the *environment.ts* file. Path should be something like: '/assets/favicons/favicon.ico' then the component should access to the environment file, create a separate component level variable for it. As a result, you can use this variable in your component html. I.e.:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ logoPath }}">
```

---

Please google a lot for this solution. This post is just helping you to start and here in stackoverflow we help to solve specific problems and not create a generic solution for you. If you run into a problem that does not have an answer here, then feel free to create a question for it.